# Get last work week of month with powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to get the last work week in a month using powershell. Right now, my code isn't working. I'm getting 5 when it should return 4. The work week is Mon-Fri Here is my code so far:

```
$d = Get-Date  ; [math]::Ceiling(($d.Day+(($d.AddDays(-($d.Day-1))).DayOfWeek.value__)-7)/7+1)
if ($d -eq 5)  { $d -=1 }
```

What can I improve or change to make this work? I'm using powershell 5.

Comment: Hi Matt you should explain what result you expect say for this month, a date range, begining monday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without understanding your `[math]` formula and its meaning, next code snippet shows 4 today (`2016-10-25`):

```
$d = Get-Date
$e = [math]::Ceiling(($d.Day+(($d.AddDays(-($d.Day-1))).DayOfWeek.value__)-7)/7+1)
if ($e -eq 5)  { $e -=1 }
$e
```

In your code snippet, `$d.GetTypeCode()` keeps to be `DateTime`. In other words, `$d -eq 5` always results to *false*.

Answer (score 0):

If your are up to the last monday of a month this should work

```
$d = Get-Date "2016-1-01"
$LastDayinMonth = (Get-Date "$($d.year)/$($d.month+1)/1").addDays(-1)
$Offset=[int](($LastDayinMonth.dayofweek -1)* -1)
If ($Offset -eq 1) {$Offset=-6}
$LastMonday=$LastDayinMonth.addDays($Offset)

"d             : {0}" -f $d.tostring("D")
"LastDayinMonth: {0}" -f $LastDayinMonth.tostring("D")
"LastMonday    : {0}" -f $LastMonday.tostring("D")
```

HTH